# From HP's Windows XP Media Center to Windows 7 Ultimate, possible?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, license

Some time ago i've bought a pc from HP.

It was a media center pc and obviously in it was pre-installed "Windows XP Media Center 2005 Edition".

Now i'm intererested to get Windows 7 Ultimate with some discount "transforming" this old license of XP.
By your knowing, it is possible?

Comment: My main problem is if my oem license of windows xp is eligible to upgrade to windows 7...

Comment: My second problem is if i can upgrade only having serial number (that computer fried and now i have another motherboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what discount you are talking about, I assume you are talking about buying an upgrade license versus a full license, in that case, I don't see why you can't purchase an upgrade edition of Windows 7 Ultimate.  Their own website clearly states:

> Do I buy an Upgrade or Full license of Windows 7?
>
> All editions of Windows XP and Windows Vista qualify you to upgrade. So, if you're running either on your PC today, buy a package labeled "Upgrade".
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/upgrade-considerations.aspx

Keep in mind you'll also need to do a custom (clean) install since you are coming from XP to 7.

UPDATE:

You mentioned you have the serial number only, you might be interested to know that the upgrade discs allow for a clean install granted you may have to do a double install.  Honestly, the upgrade editions have an unusual amount of faith in the consumer, more than you would expect from Microsoft.  I don't see any reason why anyone would really have to buy anything other than the upgrade edition, granted you don't have a guilty conscience.  The following article explains the process.

http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/clean_install_upgrade_media.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Because you already have Windows XP you are elible for an upgrade licence of Windows 7 at a cheaper price.

Note that you will need to do a 'clean install' because the Windows 7 installer does not support doing an in-place upgrade from XP to 7. This means you will have to install your programs all over again.

Answer (score 0):

You can yes but if your PC came with XP installed then it's likely that you have an OEM licence.  They're cheaper than the full licence but are tied to the machine they were purchased with.  Upgrading to Win 7 is still a valid upgrade path apparently but your copy of Win 7 will also be tied to the machine as you're upgrading an OEM licence.  This means that technically you can't use that copy of Win 7 should you at some point upgrade your machine.

Comment: UPDATE, You mention the fact that you have a different motherboard.  I suspect that Win 7 will still activate anyway so no worries there.  You may run into a problem if you have to replace the motherboard again in the next couple of years but I don't think they're very strict anyway and a quick phone call will sort it out.